# SVN Merge issue .. is not the same repository as

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I am working in a .net project and clients use SVN as source control. Currently we have a trunk version of the code which is in `svn://svnserver.com/Code/Trunk` and a branch is also present which is `svn://svnserver.com/Code/Branches/Myteam`. We are downloading the code from branch and working in our local machine and committing code changes in the branch

Now I wanted to merge the code changes from branch to trunk. When I started merging from BRANCH to TRUNK, I get the following error

> svn://svnserver.com/Code/Trunk is not the same error as
>   svn://svnserver

I don't know what's going wrong. But I am new to using SVN so I am not sure how to get rid of this error.

For both TRUNK and BRANCH, I have mapped my local folder correctly and the code is downloaded without any issues.

But only merging is becoming a problem. Do I need to do any settings in SVN? Any help wpuld be appreciated?

Comment: Something else is wrong here.  The error message as shown doesn't make sense.  Either you typed it wrong, or it's simply not the right error message.  Can you put in the actual, correct error message?  Also, can you run `svn info` on Trunk and your branch (Branches/Myteam).  I could believe that you're somehow referencing 2 different repositories... which would be a problem.

Comment: @jszakmeister it think he just mistyped it. The error should be "...is not the same repository as..."

Comment: @jszakmeister You are correct. It looked like during the merge the URL to merge from was incorrect. I need to explicitly correct it and then it worked fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SARAVAN I just had the same issue. It appeared that I probably used the FQDN for the svn server in my branch while I had my trunk url use just the host name of the svn server. What I did is I tried to merge again but this time I added the domain name to the svn server when selecting the trunk url and that seemed to work. I am curious if you ended up doing the same thing or not..? (since I see in your post svnserver.com vs. svnserver)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that you always access your SVN server using the exact same URL. Even if your SVN server is accessible using either `svn://server/repos` or `svn://server.company.com/repos` you have to make sure that you use the same URL for both branches.

If you have a working copy where you want to change/correct the URL of the server, then you can use the "TortoiseSVN->Relocate..." command to do so.